# Binding and returning text data with sqlite3 and C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to get back into programming for a personal project I would like to work on but I am having trouble figuring out the sqlite3 c/c++ api.  I am modifying code snippets I found at various tutorials and I'm trying to get them return data and field names from a database.  Here is the section of code that I am having difficulty with:

```
  sqlite3 *db;
  sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt;
  int col_num;
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  const char   *zSql = "SELECT ?,? FROM basic_table";
  string s = "Field1";
  string t = "Field2";
  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,zSql,-1,&ppStmt,0);  
  sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt,1,s.c_str(),s.length(),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt,2,t.c_str(),t.length(),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

  if(rc)
  {
    cerr << "SQL error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    col_num = sqlite3_column_count(ppStmt);
    do
    {
      rc = sqlite3_step(ppStmt);
      switch(rc)
      {
        case SQLITE_DONE:
          break;
        case SQLITE_ROW:
          for( int i=0; i<col_num; i++)
          {
            cout << sqlite3_column_name(ppStmt, i) << " " << 
             sqlite3_column_text(ppStmt,i) << endl;
          }
          break;
        default:
          cerr << "Inside error " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
          break;
      }
    } while( rc==SQLITE_ROW );
    sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt);
```

The column_name return the correct value but the data just comes back with a question mark.  I can get the code to work by calling sqlite3_exec with a callback function but the documentation for sqlite3 recommends using sqlite3_prepare_v2, sqlite3_bind, sqlite3_step, and sqlite3_finalize instead of this method so I am just trying to see if I can get that method to work.  Is there a simple error which I am making?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The *name* of these columns is `?`, because that is how they are written in the query.

The *values* of these columns are `Field1` and `Field2`, because you told the database that you want to have these string values returned by the SELECT.

The database works as designed.

[Parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) can be used only to replace the value of an expression; you cannot use them to replace identifiers such as column/table names.
You have to write the column names directly in the SQL statement:

```
const char *zSql = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM basic_table";
```